# C# XNA Load Model Error

Tags: c#, model, xna, load

I tried to load a model in XNA using `model = Content.Load<Model>("Ship");` in `LoadContent()` method (`public Model model;` = i declared the model), but I get an exception:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentLoadException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.Xna.Framework.dll
>
> Additional information: Error loading "Ship". File contains
>   Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Graphics.NodeContent but
>   trying to load as Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.Model.

What should I do?

P.S. I used a .x file and I also tried using a `.fbx` file.

P.P.S. I saw a question with this line as a solution `Content.RootDirectory = "Content";` and I already have it.

Comment: load model in `LoadContent` not in `Draw` method. Draw method is executed 60 times per second, and is only for drawing loaded objects.

Comment: protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

            model = Content.Load<Model>("Ship");
        }

Comment: That is the LoadContent() Method. I'm not sure I understand you.

Comment: @DavorMlinaric I actually was writing this quickly so I didn't notice that I actually wrote model = Content.Load("Ship"); in Draw(), because I was thinking about it, but actually I put it in LoadContent() method. Fixed now!

Comment: Fixed the problem or the question? Anyway, if you are not sure about the content folder try adding a spritebatch and load that. Other then that try to import a clean fbx, just the model. Also i remeber back when i tried importing models that not every FBX exporter is compatible with XNA.

Comment: I will definitely try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! Click on your model in the Solution Explorer, and open its Properties window.

Find the XNA Framework Content Pipeline section

Asset Name: If Asset Name is empty, put something in it (for example if you are loading a car model put car in this field) and load it with the asset name like this

```
(model name here)=Content.Load<Model>("(Asset name)");
```

In the example above (car model) it will be

```
model=Content.Load<Model>("car"); //Declare a Model called model first
```

Content Importer: FBX models = Autodesk FBX - XNA Framework | X models = X File - XNA Framework

Content Processor: Model - XNA Framework

And that's it!